# Multithread, Linq to Sql, ConcurrentDictonary Fails Remove

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq

I have a ConcurrentDictionary of Attributes for products. These attributes have the product ID and values for the names of the attribute and any options the attribute has. I have this ConcurrentDictionary because I have threads that are created to handle each attribute in the dictionary by attribute name.

```
 if (knownAttribute.AttributeType.Value.Equals("Product Specification"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Started a thread for: " + knownAttribute.AttributeTypeId + ", " + knownAttribute.Value);
                while (true)
                {

                   /* if (AS400SpecificationAttributes.IsEmpty && knownSpecificationBag.IsEmpty && gatherRowsTasks.All(x => x.IsCompleted))
                        break;*/
                    AS400SpecificationAttribute AS400SpecificationAttributeWork = null;
                    AS400SpecificationAttributeWork = knownSpecificationBag.Keys.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AttributeName == knownAttribute.Value);

                    if (AS400SpecificationAttributeWork != null)
                    {
                        var product = ctx.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProductNumber == AS400SpecificationAttributeWork.ProductNumber);
                        if (product == null)
                            continue;
                        var productAttribute = new ProductAttribute();
                        productAttribute.Attribute = knownAttribute;
                        if (AS400SpecificationAttributeWork.AttributeValue != null)
                        {
                        var knownAttributeOption = ctx.AttributeOptions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attribute.Equals(knownAttribute) && x.Value.Equals(AS400SpecificationAttributeWork.AttributeValue));

                        if (knownAttributeOption == null)
                        {
                            knownAttributeOption = new AttributeOption();
                            knownAttributeOption.Value = AS400SpecificationAttributeWork.AttributeValue;
                            knownAttributeOption.Attribute = knownAttribute;
                            ctx.AttributeOptions.InsertOnSubmit(knownAttributeOption);
                            ctx.SubmitChanges();
                        }
                            productAttribute.AttributeOption = knownAttributeOption;
                            productAttribute.AttributeOptionId = knownAttributeOption.Id;
                        }
                        product.ProductAttributes.Add(productAttribute);
                        ctx.SubmitChanges();
                        string tmpstr = null;
                        if (!knownSpecificationBag.TryRemove(AS400SpecificationAttributeWork, out tmpstr))
                            Thread.Sleep(50);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (tryCounter < 5)
                        {
                            tryCounter++;
                            Thread.Sleep(1000);
                            Console.WriteLine("Thread waiting for work: Product Specification:" + knownAttribute.Value);
                            continue; 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            int outVal;
                            threadTracker.TryRemove("Product Specification:" + knownAttribute.Value, out outVal);
                            Console.WriteLine("Closing Thread: Product Specification:" + knownAttribute.Value);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(50);
                }
```

It seems like the following Attribute element refuses to be removed.
[image]

I don't understand why. If i put it in a while(!dic.tryRemove(ele)) it will forever be stuck and never move from there.

There may be an error somewhere within the thread but I have no idea why.

Comment: I can't see the whole context - but what would happen if the item was never in the dictionary or if two threads both executed the same code, so one of them removed it and for the other thread it wasn't there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement proper equals and gethashcode when using TryRemove

```
 public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return new { this.name, this.value, this.group, this.productNumber }.GetHashCode(); 
    }

    public bool Equals(AS400SpecificationAttribute other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return false;
        return (this.ProductNumber.Equals(other.productNumber) && ((this.group != null && this.group.Equals(other.AttributeGroup)) || (this.group == null && other.AttributeGroup == null)) && ((this.name!= null && this.name.Equals(other.AttributeName)) || (this.name == null && other.AttributeName == null)) && ((this.value != null && this.value.ToUpper().Equals(other.AttributeValue.ToUpper())) || (this.value == null && other.AttributeValue == null))); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This statement

```
if (!knownSpecificationBag.TryRemove(AS400SpecificationAttributeWork, out tmpstr))
```

will always return `true` or `false`. It won't block. That's the behavior of `ConcurrentDictionary`. It will return `false` if the key is not in the dictionary.

If you're looping while that method returns false and it's stuck, that means that the item isn't in the dictionary when the loop begins. Either it either was never in the dictionary or that another thread already removed it.

Is your intention to loop until the item is *not* in the dictionary?
You could try this:

```
if (!knownSpecificationBag.TryRemove(AS400SpecificationAttributeWork, out tmpstr) 
    && !knownSpecificationBag.ContainsKey(AS400SpecificationAttributeWork))
```

Comment: Couldn't the missing item be added back between the calls to `TryRemove()` and `ContainsKey()` though? Isn't this just pushing the race further?

Comment: I believe that FirstorDefault is returning that one object and the TryRemove keeps failing and it keeps looping through the same element.